# How to apply adjustbox on an algorithm(2e)

Tags: two-column, algorithms, algorithm2e, adjustbox

I have a double page document and I wish to add an algorithm at a certain point. But if I just include the algorithm (of the algorithm2e package) then the text gets really bad since many lines of the algorithm break the column.

So I have my algorithm some thing like

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,lined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line
\begin{document}

    \title{For the Horde!}
    
    \author
    { 
        \IEEEauthorblockN{  Broxigar the Ax \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}}
        {
            \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
                \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}
                    Orgrimmar, Azeroth
                \end{tabular}  
            \end{tabular}
        }
    }
    \maketitle
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
    
    \section{Erroneous Algorithm}
    
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=0.5\textwidth} % half the pagewidth
         \begin{algorithm}[tbh]
              \SetAlgoLined
              \SetKwFunction{INT}{Intersection}
              \SetKwFunction{UN}{Union}
              \SetKwFunction{MAX}{Maximize}
    
              \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
              \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
    
              \Input{Tree integer numbers, one prime number and one banana}
              \Output{The circumference of our planet}
    
              \BlankLine
   
              \For{$i \leftarrow 0$ \KwTo $100,000,000$}
              {
             \tcp*[h]{Maximize the minimized value twice}
             \MAX{this\_is\_going\_to\_break\_the\_column\_width\_for\_sure,tw}\;
             }
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

And I want to 'wrap' that with an adjustbox in order to make it fit. Like

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,lined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line
\begin{document}

    \title{For the Horde!}
    
    \author
    { 
        \IEEEauthorblockN{  Broxigar the Ax \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}}
        {
            \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
                \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}
                    Orgrimmar, Azeroth
                \end{tabular}  
            \end{tabular}
        }
    }
    \maketitle
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
    
    \section{Erroneous Algorithm}
    
    \begin{algorithm}[tbh]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \SetKwFunction{INT}{Intersection}
    \SetKwFunction{UN}{Union}
    \SetKwFunction{MAX}{Maximize}
    
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
    
    \Input{Tree integer numbers, one prime number and one banana}
    \Output{The circumference of our planet}
    
    \BlankLine
    
        
    \For{$i \leftarrow 0$ \KwTo $100,000,000$}
    {
        \tcp*[h]{Maximize the minimized value twice}
        \MAX{this\_is\_going\_to\_break\_the\_column\_width\_for\_sure,tw}\;
    }
    \end{algorithm}
    
\end{document}
\end{adjustbox}
```

The problem is that when I try to do it like that, I get a compilation error. This does not work. Are there any workarounds for this?

I also don't wish for \tcp*[h] comments to break is this possible? To shrink them in one line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please prepare a complete minimal working example and add it to your question. With such an example file, others can reproduce the output you get.

Comment: What exactly does "double page" and "break the column" refer to here? Do you have a twocolumn layout (two columns of text per page)?

Comment: Yes a two column layout. Two columns of text per page @leandriis . Take the MCVE that I edited if it suits you

Comment: @Broxigar: Note that `width-\textwidth` is not correct; you're probably interested in `width=\textwidth`.

Comment: Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows what exactly you do. By default, overly wide lines in an `algorithm2e` `algorithm` environment should be broken into multiple lines avoiding an overlap with the adjacent column's text. If that's not the case in your document, this must be caused by something you did not show yet.

Comment: Also, if you use `\begin{algorithm}[H]` in a `twocolumn` documentclass, you should get an error message such as: "! LaTeX Error: [H] in two columns mode is not allowed for algorithms.
"

Comment: @Broxigar: Instead of "double page" are you referring to a `twocolumn` document?

Comment: @Werner I have added an MWE

Comment: @leandriis Yes, I have edited the post it works now.

Comment: Use `algorithm*` which will typeset the algorithm in single column format. Reducing the font size is a sure way to make your readers unhappy.

Comment: @egreg I cannot ''afford'' to give up the space it consumes when breaking the double columns. Its one of the reasons I need adjustbox. To also shrink it.